# How to create small bullets within a subsubsection

Tags: bullets

I'm trying to figure out how to shrink the bullet points within my subsubsections. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
...


\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\bfseries}
{}
{-.12em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\large}
{}
{0em}
{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\large}
{\hspace*{.25in}$\bullet$}
{.5em}
{}

\titlespacing{\subsubsection}
{0em}{-.25em}{0em}

\titlespacing{\subsection}
{0em}{.25em}{0em}

\setlength\parindent{25pt}

\begin{document}

...

\section{\vspace*{-.7em} Education}
\subsection{{\vspace*{-.25em} school} \hfill \normalsize location}
\subsubsection{B.S. Candidate \hfill \normalsize May 2023} \subsubsection{Relevant Coursework: previous courses currently \vspace*{-.25em} \linebreak \phantom{1em} \: current courses} \subsubsection{GPA}


...

\thispagestyle{empty} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

Try with the below:

```
%%Small bullet
\newcommand{\smallbullet}{} % for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand\smallbullet{%
  \mathord{\mathpalette\smallbullet@{0.75}}%
}
\newcommand{\smallbullet@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}%
}
```

Then use `\smallbullet` instead of `\bullet`

Actually, this was suggested by some one else, but I missed the `URL` link...

Comment: Hmm I got the errors "\smallbullet already defined", "missing $ inserted", "illegal paramater number in the definition" and "can't use macro parameter # in math mode". I'm using Texmaker btw :) Thanks for your help

Comment: The code ` \subsubsection{Relevant Coursework: previous courses currently \vspace*{-.25em} \linebreak \phantom{1em} \: current courses} \subsubsection{GPA}` produced the error, may I know why you need `\vspace` and `\phantom`, etc. inside `\subsubsection` tag?